# React page showing only for a few seconds when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron, react-router-dom

I am working on this sidebar navigation, and supposedly when the link is clicked it should show the page, but as I have observed during run time, the page is only there for a split second then both the sidebar and everything in the home page is completely wiped off.

There is no error in the console log that is why I have no clue which part should I fix.

Here is my code for the routing

```
import { 
  HashRouter as Router, 
  Route, 
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Profile from '../components/Profile';
import DirectMsg from '../components/DirectMsg';
import TeamMsg from '../components/TeamMsg';

const Home = () => {
  return(
    <div className='page'> 
      <Router>
        <SideBar chats={joinedChats}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/profile">
              <Profile/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/direct">
              <DirectMsg/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/team">
              <TeamMsg/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </SideBar>   
      </Router>     
   
      <div className='channelpannel'>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

And here is the Sidebar.js file

```
import React, { useState }  from 'react';
import { 
  RiUserFill,
  RiNavigationFill,
  RiGamepadFill,
  RiMore2Fill
} from "react-icons/ri"

import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


const SideBar = ({children}) => {
  const[isOpen ,setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen (!isOpen);
  const menuItem=[
    {
      path: "/profile",
      name: "Profile",
      icon: <RiUserFill/>
    },
    {
      path: "/direct",
      name: "Direct Message",
      icon: <RiNavigationFill/>
    },
    {
      path: "/team",
      name: "Team Message",
      icon: <RiGamepadFill/>
    },
  ]

  return (
    <div className='sidebarpannel'>
      <div style={{width: isOpen ? "40%" : "10%"}}className='sidemenu'>
        <div className='top_section'>
          <h1 style={{display: isOpen ? "block" : "none"}} className='logo'>Weedle</h1>
          <div style={{marginLeft: isOpen ? "5%" : "0%"}} className='bars'> 
            <RiMore2Fill onClick={toggle}/> 
          </div>
        </div> 
        {menuItem.map((item, index) => (
          <NavLink to={item.path} key={index} className="link" activeClassName="active">
            <div className='icon'>{item.icon}</div>
            <div style={{display: isOpen ? "block" : "none"}} className='link_text'>{item.name}</div>
          </NavLink>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className='sidecontent'>{children}</div> 
    </div>
  )
}

export default SideBar;
```

And here is one of the pages

```
import React from 'react';

const Profile = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Profile</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Profile;
```

Here is a screenshot of where I would like the contents of the toggled route to be in. [image: the class is "sidecontent"]

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the code you've provided. Does the render issue persist when rendering the app into the browser vs in an electron app container? Think you could try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: does the console in devtools say anything when this happens?  I would l maybe lift the isOpen state/dispatch up into Home and pass them down to Sidebar

Comment: Hi there @DrewReese! I am not familiar with codesandbox and as I tried using it, I can't seem to import my rep to codesandbox. Will it be ok if I'll just paste my repo from github, here? Here's the link to it. [Repo to the project](https://github.com/vagabondachi/Weedle-ChatApp)

Comment: Instead of trying to import the entire repo/project (which *is* possible in the sandbox), the idea here on SO is to distill your app/code down to a [mcve] that reproduces the issue. This makes it easier to get straight to the code causing the problem without wading through all the code that is irrelevant. Often times it's the case that when reducing the code down for a minimal example here you'll actually find the cause of an issue yourself.